# How to decode special character in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

How to decode spacial character in xamairn forms

Inside my label text = "Sample & Text"
instead of showing original text, its showing `"Sample &amp; Text"`

so how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to display '&' with the text?

Comment: Yes I want to show &.How to do that?

Comment: I have posted the answer check if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&amp;` is used for displaying `&` in XAML. If you want to display **Sample & Text** on code behind, there's no need to encode it to `Sample &amp; Text`. You could set the value directly. i.e. here is a list view's items source:

```
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var str = "Sample & Text";
    list.Add(str);
}
listView.ItemsSource = list;
```

It shows correctly:

[image]

However, if your original text from the server is `Sample &amp; Text` and you want to display the decoded format, you can try `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`:

```
var str = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Sample &amp; Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Label Text="Sample &amp;Text"/>
```

This will display "Sample & Text"

Comment: I have a listview,so how to do this inside Listview label?

Comment: You can simply append "&" with the string, &amp; is required when is it used directly  from XAML

Comment: actually the text are coming form server and saved into local database(sqlite).and this data getting from local db so that is the reason its showing the encoded value.how to solve this?

Comment: You can write a logic to find substring &amp; and replace with "&"